# Can't start Scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy

Pretty sure that everything is installed correctly. When I go into the python interpreter and import scrapy, no error is raised. However, when I run `scrapy startproject tutorial` in the shell, it returns:

```
$ scrapy startproject tutorial
-bash: scrapy: command not found
```

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: you need to add scrapy to your environment path

Comment: I've run `PATH=$PATH\:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy` and tried running `scrapy startproject tutorial` once again, but it still doesn't work. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: You're missing `export` on the `PATH=...` line.

Comment: Ok, just tried with `export` prepended - still no luck...

Comment: Are you sure that a `scrapy` executable is found at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sit‌​e-packages/scrapy`?

Comment: Ok it was an installation issue - I reinstalled and works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Scrapy solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem and even I reinstall python and scrapy still not work.
After that, I switched from zsh to default shell(Mac OS X 10), it works fine now.